# Trim trailing whitespace upon leaving a modified line

Tags: whitespace

I once had emacs trim trailing whitespace upon leaving a line, if that line had been modified.

Note: I already have trim at save, it is not what I am asking for here. I have the package ws-butler, but it seems to only act on save.

It was working with my previous config in emacs 26, but I cannot see a package other than ws-butler there, I suspect it might be some built-in I fail to configure?

What could possibly have been doing that trimming?

Comment: Maybe [ws-trim.el](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/DeletingWhitespace)(search for ws-trim on the page)? The canonical distribution was hosted on the `lysator` FTP server. I found a copy at https://github.com/windley/emacs/blob/master/ws-trim.el however.

Comment: did you have a hook calling [delete-trailing-whitespace](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Useless-Whitespace.html)?

Comment: @NickD: you got it, thanks!! I even had a copy of `ws-trim.el` in my old config repo, although the setting up of it was gone from the init.el.

Comment: @NickD If you want to make an answer of your comment, I'd gladly give you the internet points.

Comment: Glad that the `ws-trim` mention helped, but I'd rather you provided an answer that describes how *you* use it to answer your question. Just mentioning `ws-trim` was easy but I would have to do significant amounts of research to provide a good answer and I won't have the time to do that any time soon - if ever !-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to @NickD for finding the package I was missing: [ws-trim](https://github.com/windley/emacs/blob/master/ws-trim.el).

It is mentioned [here](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/DeletingWhitespace#:%7E:text=lines%20you%E2%80%99ve%20edited.-,ws%2Dtrim.el,-%2D%20an%20old%20but), which is where I found it in the first place, long ago.

Download the source, put it somewhere in emacs load-path (I have `(add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d/includes")` in my init).

The following gives me the minor mode with the behavior I am looking for:

```
;; ws-trim trims trailing whitespace at navigating from line.
(require 'ws-trim)
(setq ws-trim-level 1) ; 1 -> only modified lines are trimmed.
(setq ws-trim-method-hook '(ws-trim-trailing))
```

Comment: One nit: it is preferable to use `add-hook` to modify a hook: for one, it checks for duplicates, thereby avoiding problems down the line; also, if it has some functions on it already, the `setq` will get rid of them - that might be a big problem. It is not much of a problem here (presumably, nobody else - some library or package - would want to add anything to it), but it is a good habit to get into. Just replace the last setq with `(add-hook 'ws-trim-method-hook #'ws-trim-trailing)`.

Comment: @NickD The lib does this: `;;;###autoload (defvar ws-trim-method-hook '(ws-trim-leading ws-trim-trailing))`. Isn't `add-hook` going to just add to the list? I don't want to trim leading, so I thought the hook needed replacing?

Comment: You are right that you need to replace it. It's unfortunate that the library does that initialization (IMO). I would rather have it give you an empty hook that users can populate as they want. In this case, I would add a `(defvar ws-trim-method-hook nil)` before `ws-trim.el` is loaded to enforce my preference and then use `add-hook` in my regular way, but it *is* a minor nit.